# Designing an Order object for Trading systems

Tags: java, oop, trading, fix-protocol

I am trying to design my first trading system and I am struggling with designing a correct Order object with all the `FIX` concepts involved in it. Wondering if any experienced folks can chime in on some ideas.

I created a simple Order class. 
But as a `NewOrderSingle` (FIX) is generated, I need a `ClOrdId`.
Then when I cancel this order, I need a new `ClOrdId` (For every cancel and replace FIX message generated) and set the correct `OrigClOrdId`. So I need to keep track of those `OrigClOrdIds`.

Also, I think I need to keep a unique Id internal to my system to identify this order, different from `ClOrdId`, which could keep changing.

I don't see any nice object oriented way of designing this order object while keeping the concept of various Ids relevant to my FIX messages separate.

How do people design these in real world? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: (http://www.quickfixj.org/) QuickfixJ is an open source library. You can have a check through it and chart out your own implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

I have been involved with the design of several systems that do exactly what you are describing. It is actually more complicated than designing a class hierarchy.  Some things to keep in mind:

Based on the trading venue and/or asset class, the "unique ID" of the order may actually be a combination of tags. For example, when trading on NYSE "Classic" the unique ID is actually a compound ID consisting of tag 115 (OnBehalfOfCompID) + Tag 11.  For other venues, it could be Tag 109 + Tag 11, or Tag 76 + Tag 11.

In addition, you may need to add more data to your unique ID to account for the fact that IDs sent to distinct venues could be the same. For example, some venues require an `Integer` as their ClOrdID value. In such cases, your internal representation of the "unique ID" should be some kind of salt + the ID data, i.e. `DARKCROSS-1` where the (fictional) venue is "DARKCROSS" and `1` is the tag 11 value.

If several venues have a similar strategy for resolving the unique ID of the order, you could extract that logic into a ID factories - composition over inheritance.

So, your abstraction could start with a `AbstractOrder`, but you may find that you need to have `NyseOrder`, `NasdaqOrder`, and so on.

(Note that some implementations I've seen have a `GenericFixOrder` class or some such. In practice, there is no such thing - each venue has its own specific behavior that is slightly different from others.)

Another topic is Good Til Cancel and Good Til Date orders, which generally must have IDs that are unique for all time (i.e. the ID must contain a date), and which survive your application for multiple restarts. So, your ID factory must take such orders into account.

Regarding relationship of the IDs, it is actually quite straight-forward. You have a `Map` of unique order IDs to `Order` objects.  The class representing a Cancel/Replace or Cancel references the parent order (via a "Parent Order ID" field, resolved the same as the "Unique ID" field as described above).

There does not have to be a direct reference to the original ("root") New Order, in fact when the Cancel/Replace is accepted you may find it beneficial to remove it from the `Map` holding your orders. When the Cancel is accepted, you almost definitely can remove both it and the Order from the `Map` - the order is complete.

Note that the above is a general sketch - removing orders from memory, etc. could be considered a premature optimization. If your trading volumes are small, you could possibly hold all of your trading messages in memory for the entire day.

Answer (score 1):

How about this class diagram?

[image: Order class diagram]

Cancel method constructs new `SubOrder` that can be used to send cancel request. You could add more constructor methods for other sub order types. If cancellation order is very specific you could crate one class per order type, if they have something in common they could extend common class, `AbstractOrder` for example. Something like that:

[image: Class diagram with generalization]

Comment: @user1364959 [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) it is not exactly UML tool but it is free.